# Should an employee express disagreement with workflow of manager during in their annual review?

Tags: management, employer

My company switched managers about 4 months ago. The guy has a great track record and many of us, including me, look up to him.

However, he has been changing the workflow of my team a lot. This is resulting in a downfall in our numbers.

My annual report is coming up and each member of the team will have to explain their part in the raised or fallen numbers. Do I express my disagreement during this time? I will be held responsible for the bad numbers, while it really was not my fault or idea.

How should I proceed with this?

Comment: Why are you being held responsible for something you have no control over? That also seems to be pointing to a problem.

Comment: If you try to convince him, make sure to choose your words carefully so as to blame the new approach and not the person implementing it. As much as it pains me to say it, making it seem like it's not his fault will make him more agreeable.

Comment: I strongly encourage you to roll back your edit. You've removed a lot of details that really made your situation more clear.

Comment: @jpmc26 I understand this but have found the answers to be sufficient and accepted it. I can either remove details or remove the question as a colleague asked me today if this was a post I made.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Produce graphs showing conversion rates for the last 12 months. Overlay them with graphs for the previous 12 months, so that annual trends are shown (or not). Indicate where you ended your data driven workflow and moved to the new 'finger in the air' workflow.

Let the graphs do the talking. You're then not attacking the manager directly, but saying that results previously were better than currently, and you claim that the reason is because the workflow changed.

Comment: +1 Document **EVERYTHING** create a paper trail, and let the chips fall where they may

Answer (score 7):

No. Pointing fingers back at your boss is not going to be productive for you. The numbers are the numbers, your boss knows them and during your review is not the time to challenge his leadership or his choice of direction. All that it will do is point out that you are not someone that he can count on to support him, and he is likely to look at your opposition to his policies as the reason why you are not contributing as much as he expects.

Instead focus on what you did that helped improve the numbers, and anything you did that did not work.  Acknowledge your failures and address how you are going to make it better.  It is fine to include specifics about how you implemented his directions here, as long as you are pointing out the effects it had that lead to reduction in the numbers; but avoid making it sound like you are making an excuse.  Instead accept the responsibility for doing it, and with out placing any blame on the policy.  If everyone is having the same problem then the boss can infer a problem with the policy.  If most others are having success then the problem may actually be your implementation and this method could help you improve your numbers.

What you can do is explain what you would like to do differently that you believe would improve the numbers.  Try not to challenge his direction with these but instead small changes that align with what he has been advocating.

I understand the desire to do better, but in the corporate world there is more to it than just results.  Numbers can be made to appear to show what ever you want them to.  And your boss is the one who gets to decide what they show.  Do not give him reason to show that your poor performance last year is a major contributing factor to the decline in the numbers.  Someday when you are the boss it will be your directions you want followed and you can do things your way.

Comment: "Should an employee express disagreement with manager..." Yes! "... in writing during their annual review?" NOOOOOO!!!!

Comment: @Stannius - And definately not as a see I told you so.

Comment: Really bad suggestion to take responsibility of a failing manager. That's just hiding the things under the rug. If numbers were 'just' numbers, they would not be collected and analyzed. Numbers is the most important source of reliable measurable data, not a vague let-me-bend-my-opinion-into-the-ultimate-truth! Yes, finding right wording is important for nor creating enemies. Diplomacy you know... But again. Do not kiss the manager's bottom if you care about your company or your own future in it. If you do, the manager will quickly get used to it and the issue will keep growing.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko - Not disagreeing with you on any of that.  But during your review is not the time for that.  Your review is about you not about your manager.  You are not accepting responsibility for the manager, you are taking responsibility for your results.  There are times where that is much more appropriate.